# jwplayer should play video after it is buffered

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, buffering

I want that my video should start playing after it is buffered 10% of the duration. Any Leads how I can do it using getBuffer() and onBufferChange() method .. Source code will be highly helpful .

Thanks,

Comment: How are you encoding the video?

Comment: Ethan , Do you mean the codecs ?.. It can be in H264/H263 .

Comment: No I mean how are you encoding your video, specific encoding settings.

Answer (score 1):

The player starts playing the video long before it gets to 10% buffering - it usually starts within just a few seconds, if not immediately. If you're finding that you have to wait for the entire video to download, it's because it's encoded improperly, with the **moov atom** at the end of the file, rather than at the beginning.

The quickest fix is to grab a little free application called **MP4 FastStart** from here: http://www.datagoround.com/lab/. You can feed it single video files, or an entire folder. It does only one thing - it puts the **moov atom** where it belongs. It's very quick.

Another option is to re-encode using **Handbrake** - http://handbrake.fr/. Take the default settings, but also check **Web Optimized**.

If you're using **ffmpeg**, include the **-movflags faststart** option.